# Different Result of XMLHttpRequest call in Chrome and Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a chrome extension and a firefox addon which contain the same code in the background script:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
var url = "https://www.example.com/me/index.php";


request.open("GET", url, true);
request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    if (request.status == 200)
    {
        extractData(request.response);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("request.status " + request.status);
    }
```

In the chrome extension I get a status 200 and can read the data

in the firefox webextension I get the error 404. But this worked too until 4 weeks ago when suddenly the firefox addon got this server response.

What's the difference between the XMLHttpRequest in Chrome and Firefox extension?

Comment: Can you remove the space `https://www.example.com /me/index.php`   before `/me` and try?

Comment: Sorry, that was only an error here in the post. in the orginal code there is no space. I copy&paste the original url from the code into the browser to check if the url is correct. The original code was working fine until 4 weeks ago and I didn't change something